# Pass an object to a widget in template

Tags: dojo

I have a Dojo UI widget that has a widget embedded within it. I need to pass an object to this embedded widget for it to set itself up correctly, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I have been templating in the embedded widget in the template for the wrapper widget, for example:

```
...<div class="thing"
        data-dojo-type="mycompany.widgets.ComplexEmbeddedWidget"
        data-dojo-props="stuff: '${stuff}'"></div>...
```

but this doesn't seem to work, I guess the data is passed as a string maybe?

I'm pulling out this data by setting it to a property in the embedded widget and then referencing it in my `postMixInProperties` function.

Doubtless this is the wrong approach, what should I be doing to set up an embedded widget such as this?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are going to use this approach, you want to convert the javascript object json before it is passed to the templated  embedded widget.

You can easily do this by requiring 'dojo/json' and doing

```
this.stuff=jsonModule.stringify(this.stuffAsObject);
```

As you have already discovered, if you are setting more complex properties, programmatic instantiation is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If your `mycompany.widgets.ComplexEmbeddedWidget` is desperate to have the object 'stuff' set allready once it is initialized (in constructor), then im not sure this approach will do, however a simple fix could be removing the ' quotes around ${stuff}?

What happens is basically that you derive the widget with dijit/_TemplatedMixin. This in turn, during buildRendering, calls _stringRepl on 'this' (the widget). I am not completely certain of the flow, since youre working with WidgetsInTemplate..

lets as example, set a widgets attribute to an array via markup:

```
<div 
   data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Select" 
   data-dojo-props="options:[ 'val1', 'val2']">
</div>
```

As you see, no quotes around the value - or it will render as a string. Lets then change your ComplexEmbedded template to

```
dojo.declare("exampleName", [_WidgetsInTemplateMixin, _TemplatedMixin], {
 templateString: '<div class="outerWidgetDomNode">
  ...
  <div class="thing"
    data-dojo-type="mycompany.widgets.ComplexEmbeddedWidget"
    data-dojo-props="stuff: ${stuff}"></div>
  ...
'
});
```

To instantiate the ComplexEmbeddedWidget.stuff with an object, this needs to be a string. _Templated uses dojo.string.substitute, which probably would fail if given deep nested object.

Markup example:

```
<div data-dojo-type="exampleName" data-dojo-props="stuff: '{ json:\'Representation\', as:\'String\'}'"></div>
```

Or via programmatic

```
var myObj = { obj:'Representation', as:'Object' };
var anExampleName = new exampleName({
    stuff: dojo.toJson(myObj) // stringify here
}, 'exampleNode');
```

Lets know how goes, ive been wanting to look into the presendence of flow with this embedding widgets into template stuff for a while :)

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically insert widgets. This seems to be be the way to go if the inserted widget requires JavaScript objects to be passed to it.